# Themes for Ubuntu GRUB

Tags: grub2, themes

I have set up my laptop to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04.

I want to know how to set a theme for GRUB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grub-customizer`. Run this in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 10):

Find a theme you like e.g. https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009237/

1. Extract the theme to `/boot/grub/themes/`
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` file. Find the line starting with "#GRUB_THEME" and change it to "GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/[THEME_FOLDER]/[theme.txt]"
   (replace [THEME_FOLDER] ; [theme.txt] is probably OK ; remove "[]" brackets)
3. Run `sudo update-grub`

NB: The example given is in 7z format so you unzip it with `7z x grub_themes_stylishdark_0_1_by_vinceliuice-d8t31ig.7z`.

It also contains a deb file that you can run to copy the right files or you can copy the unzipped files. However, you have to make sure you copy the right ones. It contains files like this:

`grub-themes-stylishdark_0.1-1_all/boot/grub/themes/StylishDark/background.jpg`

You want to go to `/boot/grub/themes/` and copy the `grub-themes-stylishdark_0.1-1_all/boot/grub/themes/StylishDark` directory into it so you end up with `/boot/grub/themes/StylishDark`

P.S.: Grub themes usually come with appropriate install instructions or auto-installer. You can find lots of grub themes on https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/109/ord/latest/